# creataeuidefinition output parameters is not evaluating if condition

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

Here is my output parameter in createui looks
"fipStartAddress": "[if(contains(steps('Networking').DeploymentType,'dedicated'),'192.168.0.1','192.168.1.1')]"

but on execution from marketplace after publishing it is throwing runtime error :-

{"code":"InvalidTemplate","message":"Deployment template validation failed: 'The value for the template parameter 'virtualNetworkName' at line '54' and column '27' is not provided. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-create-parameter-file for usage details.'."}

That means it still needs that parameter value to be defined as default in mainTeamplate.json which is not I required but from UI output parameter only.

I tried execution from market place after publishing my package but it should return value based on IF condition evaluation in output section in createuidefinition to arm template's mainTemplate.json
but it is not returning same. But if i remove IF funciton and put only this
"fipStartAddress": "[steps('Networking').Fipstartaddress]"

it works fine.